# How to secure application source code when using OTA?

Tags: blackberry

I want to distribute my application via OTA. I have PROJECT_NAME.jar file in the same directory with .cod and .jad files in my ftp server. So everyone can reach .jar file. What is the best way to secure this jar?

Comment: Do not put your .jar file in the same folder. You don't need for OTA installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Micheal B. wrote as comment, I don't need to put .jar file in OTA installation folder.